# Use Row value to match column name and take value from column along same row in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

This is all through Power Query on PowerBI.

I currently have a table that looks something like this:

| Number | Vehicle | Tractor | Car | Lorry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 317968 | Car | 27/03/2022 | 21/03/2023 | 21/03/2023 |
| 312388 | Lorry | 21/01/2024 | 16/08/2021 | 11/07/2022 |
| 316671 | Car | 18/09/2022 | 24/12/2023 | 18/09/2023 |
| 318328 | Tractor | 12/01/2024 | 03/03/2023 | 21/08/2024 |
| 328543 | Tractor | 19/08/2022 | 15/11/2022 | 21/03/2023 |

I am looking at creating a new column which only takes the date from the column that matches the Vehicle column returning something like this:

| Number | Vehicle | Tractor | Car | Lorry | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 317968 | Car | 27/03/2022 | 21/03/2023 | 21/03/2023 | 21/03/2023 |
| 312388 | Lorry | 21/01/2024 | 16/08/2021 | 11/07/2022 | 11/07/2022 |
| 316671 | Car | 18/09/2022 | 24/12/2023 | 18/09/2023 | 24/12/2023 |
| 318328 | Tractor | 12/01/2024 | 03/03/2023 | 21/08/2024 | 12/01/2024 |
| 328543 | Tractor | 19/08/2022 | 15/11/2022 | 21/03/2023 | 19/08/2022 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a column by name, using the `Record.Field` function:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "New Column", each Record.Field(_,[Vehicle]))
```